# Is there yet such a thing as a "dynamic sheet of paper"?

Tags: electrical-engineering, consumer-electronics

I know about "e-ink", but I haven't heard anyone even mention that since like 2006 or something.

I'm looking for essentially a single A4 (or "Letter" size) sheet of paper which is not actually paper. That is, I wish to avoid having to frequently dig out my inkjet printer (which I don't have the physical space to keep out at all times), keep buying expensive ink for it (which likes to dry out if I don't use it often enough), and having to waste physical paper whenever I want to just show a list to somebody in the family, or have a bunch of notes handy which I have written on the computer, for example.

It would be great if I could somehow put a text document onto this "digital sheet of paper" and then it would stick on it as if it were a real sheet of paper, and preferably not require power or any kind of software/OS/booting up. I imagine that there would be some kind of USB-connected minimal wireless transmitter inserted into the PC which I can use some standardized, non-proprietary interface to send data from my machine to the "sheet of paper".

Naturally, I don't expect it to be as thin as a piece of paper, or as flexible. But I just don't want an annoying "device" which spies on me and costs a fortune and eats batteries/power and requires constant babysitting/maintenance. I definitely don't want an "iPad" or any other kind of "pad"/tablet.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: A stone slab - engrave the info on it? Or a chalk board? As you have excluded all electronic possibilities...

Comment: Sounds like you're describing this? https://youtu.be/cGsRJhoF5yY check the comments for lots of upgrade ideas

Comment: A magna doodle? You excluded batteries and software and we don't have any displays that can maintain an image without power or interface with a computer without software.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the electronic picture frames are a good candidate for what you need. they can save and display many images, including image of a sheet of text, but nothing more.

Also if you have general schematic idea  many chip builders shops in china or here in California can make it for you for reasonable price.